# Charting Tools Required, Compatible with ASP.NET or Web Forms

Tags: .net, asp.net, open-source, charts

I want to implement/use a chart below:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/iemf0h

1. The number of cells are changeable (e.g. 3x3, 5x5)
2. The colour of each cell is changeable,
3. The circle icon within the cell is changeable (e.g. diamond, triangle, or the ability to insert custom image within the cell).
4. More than one icon can be inserted within the chart, with each icon in a cell.
5. Title for X,Y axis.
6. The whole chart is re-sizeable.
7. The chart needs to be an Image (surfacing purpose).

I am using Dundas Chart, which seems not fully support it. MS Chart is based on Dundas Chart, unless MS implemented new chart!

Any suggestion on software, free or commercial, would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally, I'd write a 'simple' matrix chart like this myself.. And have full control. Try playing around with creating `n by n` tables with each cell having background and content as property, etc..

Answer (score 2):

If this is ASP.NET, you should be able to just write your own webcontrol that render this using table row and column. You can use CSS to set the background color and use image for your marker either it is diamond, circle or etc as the content to the column

Example: your webcontrol will render to something like this:

```
<table>
..........
<tr>
............
 <td class="high-risk"><img src=".\image\circlemarker.jpg"></td>
 .............
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will consider it as an option.

Answer (score 1):

you can try out with the [MS chart controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart).

Comment: Thanks. I will consider it an an option. MS Chart is based on Dundas Chart, unless MS implemented new chart

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSChart control, please follow the link
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c

Comment: @naketepe Thanks. I will consider it an an option. MS Chart is based on Dundas Chart, unless MS implemented new chart!